# Can't open a second window using PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am writing a simple inventory manager, and there is a search bar. When the item is found a button should appear and when you click it will open a second window with info about the item. But the second window won't open for some reason. I tried to put a print statement there and it printed the address of the window, but it wouldn't just show. Here is the code.

```
import json
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QLineEdit,QMainWindow


class Data:
    path: str = '/Users/simonesamardzhiev/Desktop/My projects/Inventory Management System/python/inventory.json'
    data: list[dict]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.read_data()

    def read_data(self) -> None:
        with open(self.path, "r") as file:
            self.data = json.load(file)

    def write_data(self) -> None:
        with open(self.path, "w") as file:
            json.dump(self.data, file, indent=4)

    def check_if_name_exists(self, name: str) -> bool:
        for item in self.data:
            if item["name"] == name:
                return True

        return False

    def iter_over_items(self) -> dict:
        for item in self.data:
            yield item


class ItemInfo(QWidget):
    layout: QGridLayout

    def __init__(self, item: dict) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Item info')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(QLabel('Name'), 0, 0)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class Window(QWidget):
    mainLayout: QGridLayout
    buttonForAddingItem: QPushButton
    searchEntry: QLineEdit
    results: list[QPushButton] = []
    data: Data = Data()

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Inventory Management System')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 600)

        self.mainLayout = QGridLayout()

        self.buttonForAddingItem = QPushButton("Add Item")
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonForAddingItem, 0, 0)

        self.searchEntry = QLineEdit()
        self.searchEntry.textChanged.connect(self.on_search)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.searchEntry, 1, 0)

        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

    def on_search(self, text: str) -> None:
        for result in self.results:
            self.mainLayout.removeWidget(result)

        self.results.clear()
        text = text.lower()

        row = 2
        for item in self.data.iter_over_items():
            if item["name"].startswith(text):
                button = QPushButton(item["name"])
                button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_result_pressed(item))
                self.mainLayout.addWidget(button, row, 0)
                row += 1
                self.results.append(button)

    def on_result_pressed(self, item: dict) -> None:
        info = ItemInfo(item)
        print(info)
        info.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = Window()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I think I saw the same code in other question few minutes ago.

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77672047/i-cant-change-attributes-on-my-tkinter-object-in-python-on-macos with the same string `'/Users/simonesamardzhiev/Desktop/My projects/Inventory Management System/...`  but with `tkinter`

Comment: it would be simpler if you would add example data directly in code - `self.data = ...` - so we could simply copy and run it - to test problem

Comment: you have very common mistake which you may see many questions - so I don't write it as answer. You assign new window to local variable `info` and `PyQt` removes variable (and window) from memory when it finishes `on_result_pressed`. You have to use `self.info`

Comment: BTW: this has another problem If you have two (or more) buttons then both will try to assign new widows to the same variable `self.info` and new window will remove previous window. If you want to keep opened all windows then you have to keep them on list instead of `self.info`